# Is this possible with Unity (Instead of Castle Windsor)?

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

This [blog post](http://blingcode.blogspot.com/2010/12/auto-mocking-nsubstitute-with-castle.html) shows a way to implement auto mocking with Castle Windsor and NSubstitute.

I don't know or use Castle Windsor, but I do use Unity and NSubstitute.

Is there a way to do what he shows using Unity?

---

*Here is relevant content of the post:*

First of all, register an ILazyComponentLoader into Windsor:

```
var c = new WindsorContainer();    
c.Register(Component.For<LazyComponentAutoMocker>());
```

Then, the implementation of LazyComponentAutoMocker is simply this:

```
public class LazyComponentAutoMocker : ILazyComponentLoader
{    
  public IRegistration Load(string key, Type service, IDictionary arguments)    
  {    
    return Component.For(service).Instance(Substitute.For(new[] { service }, null));    
  }    
}
```

And you’re done!  Here’s a simple unit test example using only the code from above:

```
[Test]
public void IDictionary_Add_Invoked()
{
  var dict = c.Resolve<IDictionary>();
  dict.Add(1, 1);
  dict.Received().Add(1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Unity you can write a custom container extension which does the automocking.

Based on this [article](http://www.agileatwork.com/auto-mocking-unity-container-extension/), you need something like:

EDIT: **There was a bug in my implementation sample: see this SO question**: [NSubstitute and Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373302/nsubstitute-and-unity/13373992#13373992)

So the **fixed code looks** like this:

```
public class AutoMockingContainerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var strategy = new AutoMockingBuilderStrategy(Container);

        Context.Strategies.Add(strategy, UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
    }

    class AutoMockingBuilderStrategy : BuilderStrategy
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer container;
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> substitutes 
           = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public AutoMockingBuilderStrategy(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            var key = context.OriginalBuildKey;

            if (key.Type.IsInterface && !container.IsRegistered(key.Type))
            {
                context.Existing = GetOrCreateSubstitute(key.Type);
                context.BuildComplete = true;
            }
        }

        private object GetOrCreateSubstitute(Type type)
        {
            if (substitutes.ContainsKey(type))
                return substitutes[type];

            var substitute = Substitute.For(new[] {type}, null);

            substitutes.Add(type, substitute);

            return substitute;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can register it when creating your cotainer:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(new AutoMockingContainerExtension());
```

Comment: This works well for a single object in a test. Consider this: If I have 2 objects of same type IMyInterface (which has a mocked dependency IMyInnerInterface), then each time I call Resolve<IMyInnerInterface> I get the *same* object. Is it possible to create two parent objects and be able to access their respective inner dependencies (to set expectations on)?